# Axis direction Clav DOF

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Could the developers show the Axis direction of this DOF?

Best!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2748/axis-direction-clav-dof/) by [mariof4](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/303/mariof4/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-10**:
I assume you're talking about Atlas in drcsim. `l_clav` and `r_clav` are links, that are connected by joints named `[lr]_arm_usy` and `[lr]_arm_shx`. Which joint are your curious about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Use the GUI to turn on joint visualization (View -> Joints). The axis of rotation for a joint is highlight with a circle.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0